# How to get a localized date on Django template using a specific format?

Tags: python, django, date, localization, django-templates

I am having problems to get a localized date on Django templates.

I have this in my config file:

```
LOCALE_NAME ='es_VE'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-ve'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Caracas'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

The date I want to render is  : `mydate=2016-03-21 23:59:59.999999-04:30`

This code `{{mydate|date:"d/m/Y"}}` shows **"21/03/2016"**

and this one `{{mydate|localize}}`  shows **"22 de Marzo de 2016 a las 04:29"** (22/03/2016).

I want to get the result of the localize filter using the date's filter format.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: It seems that more recent versions of Django always apply localization when using `date` now (when `USE_L10N` is `True`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using a custom template filter:

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def datedate(value,format="%d/%m/%Y"):
    try:
        return parse_datetime(value).strftime(format)
    except Exception as e:
        return ""
```

So when I did `{{mydate|datedate}}` it shows **"22/03/2016"**

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a localized custom date format. Django's documentation has something for you: [Creating custom format files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files)

Comment: What about make the date filter time-zone aware?, is that possible?

Comment: If by timezone-aware you mean you want to display the timezone associated with the datetime object, see both https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#datetime-format and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date
You won't be able to customize the timezone format, so you may need to code your own custom filter to get the output you want.

Comment: I wanted {{mydate|date:"d/m/Y"}} to show 22/03/2016 , I was thinking in a custom filter too, but I wanted to know if there was a built-in way.

Comment: Ok, I understand your concern better now. Have you tried the localtime filter? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#localtime